# How to Perl Placeholder Variable for a DBD Mysql

Tags: perl

I recently had some help with dbi and using placeholders in Perl for Mysql queries. However I am having an issue when using multiple statements for the previously declared or prepared variable in the dbi script.

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI qw(:sql_types);

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:...", ...);

## TABLE CREATION
$dbh->do("USE test;")
$dbh->do("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE day5 (id INT, temp VARCHAR(4), time TIME, sumadd INT(11))");
$dbh->do("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE humid (temp VARCHAR(4), i24 INT (10))");   
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO day5 (id,temp,time) VALUES(1,'30','03:00:00') ");
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO humid (temp,i24) VALUES('30',8321) ");

## FAILING CODE
my $inter1 = 'i24';  # Generated value
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SET \@sumadd5 = (SELECT ? FROM humid WHERE temp ='30') ");
$sth->bind_param( 1, $inter1 ); 
$sth->finish();
$dbh->do("UPDATE day5 SET sumadd= (SELECT \@sumadd5) WHERE time= '03:00:00' ");

my $sumadd = $dbh->selectrow_array("SELECT sumadd FROM day5");
print "$sumadd\n";

$dbh->disconnect();
```

`$sumadd` is undefined, but I expect `8321`.

My question is how can I make it so the @sumadd5 variable can be inserted into the above query [UPDATE day5 SET sumadd=]?  I have added some remarks in the syntax in the spirit of clarity.

IF I RUN MANUALLY BY APPLYING THE SYNTAX INTO MYSQL REMOVING PERL SPECIFICS MY TABLE UPDATE.  IF I RUN THE SCRIPT NOTHING HAPPENS TO THE TABLE AND NO ERRORS ARE DISPLAYED.

I suspect that the break is with the UPDATE, however I can't confirm the $inter1 is being passed to the placeholder.

Comment: I will update the syntax with the table creation

Comment: I did ask request but I've been downgraded to -3

Comment: Don't replace questions with new questions, and don't be surprises when arbitrarily removing quotes, adding slashes and moving parens breaks your code. Reverted the edit to restore your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem #1

You never execute the statement you prepare. Use

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q{...});
$sth->bind_param(1, $inter1); 
$sth->execute();               <---
$sth->finish();
```

Shortcut #1:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q{...});
$sth->execute($inter1);
$sth->finish();
```

Shortcut #2:

```
$dbh->do(
   q{...},
   undef,
   $inter1,
);
```

### Problem #2

```
SELECT ? ...
```

behaves as if you had done

```
SELECT "i24" ...     // As opposed to: SELECT i24 ...
```

just like

```
SELECT time ...
```

behaves as if you had done

```
SELECT '03:00:00' ...`
```

You can't build the SQL statement you are executing. You need to build it before you execute it. Use

```
$dbh->do(q{
   SET @sumadd5 = (
      SELECT }.( $dbh->quote_identifier($inter1) ).q{
        FROM humid
       WHERE temp = '30'
   )
});
```

Comment: Thanks your help is much appreciated.  I will apply the syntax and report back.

Comment: DBD::mysql::db do failed: ~~ near '\@sumadd5 = ( SELECT `i24` FROM humid WHERE temp = '30')     SEE UPDATED SYNTAX IN QUESTION

Comment: I  no longer need "\" as a Mysql variable...  I will remove it

Comment: THE ABOVE SYNTAX PRODUCES THE FOLLOWING ERROR     ***DBD::mysql::db do failed: ~~ WHERE time= '03:00:00'' AND  Use of uninitialized value $sumadd in concatenation (.) or string  ***  I AM GOING TO TRY THE '...'

Comment: I only added the "\" but I removed it.

Comment: OK IT WORKS!!!!   I had /@sumadd5 when it should have been \@sumadd5  change it to \ fixed the issue.